# HTML PHP Include but need to use different classes

Tags: html, css, php-include

On my web site I have an list that contains about 2 - 5 items depending on the day.  The list is stored in the file: menu_upcoming_events.shtml

```
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a 
        href="upcoming_events.shtml#paint_night_sep_2016" 
        title="Sat Sept 24th from 7:00-9:00 PM"
        >
        Sat Sept 24th from 7:00-9:00 PM
        <br />
        Paint Night with Bob Bowers!
        <br />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
        href="upcoming_events.shtml#two_guitars" 
        title="Sat Oct 15th from 7:30-10:00 PM"
        >
        Sat Oct 15th from 7:30-10:00 PM
        <br />
        Two Guitars / Two Bands
        <br />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
        href="upcoming_events.shtml#cooking" 
        title="Sat Nov 12th from 7:00-10:00 PM"
        >
        Sat Nov 12th from 7:00-10:00 PM
        <br />
        Father Steve Cooking
        <br />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
        href="Attachments/nothing_is_impossible.pdf" 
        target="_blank"
        title="Just Published-&quot;Nothing Is Impossible&quot; A Book by Scott Shaeffer-Duffy">
        Just Published-&quot;Nothing Is Impossible&quot;
        <br />
        A Book by Scott Shaeffer-Duffy
        <br />
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The challenge is that this list is INCLUDED in a small section of the home page (index.shtml)

```
<div class="block_right_380_text_left" >
    <p class="anchor_380">
        <a name="upcoming_events_index_page">
        Upcoming Events
        </a>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php include("menu_upcoming_events.shtml");
    ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

And it is also INCLUDED in the menu system (menu_primary.shtml)

```
  <li><a class="link4" href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
      <?php include("menu_upcoming_events.shtml");
      ?>
  </li>
```

I would like the list of items to appear differently, depending on where it's INCLUDED (part of the menu system or a DIV of the index page).  For example, the CSS for the menu system uses a sans-serif font and contains a different background color:

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%; 
    background-color: #BDB76B;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

The Index.shtml page uses a CSS class link4:

```
a.link4:link {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: inherit;
}

a.link4:visited {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: inherit;
}

a.link4:hover {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: inherit;
}

a.link4:active {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

How do I INCLUDE this one file, but have it appear differently in each of the two locations?  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Isn't the CSS *already* doing that?  `a.link4` would target the second "include" in the code above, but not the first.

Comment: No, the first "include" in the code above produces Times for a font, not Helvetica as it should.

Comment: Then it would appear that the CSS targets aren't targeting that element.  What is `ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu`?  Those classes don't exist in the code posted.  The CSS targets have to match the HTML that you want to style.

Comment: Hi David,  ul.MenuBarHorizontal and a.MenuBarItemSubmenu code is part of the SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css file.  It came with an old version of Deamweaver years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really very little link between your posted CSS and your posted include....

The **only** thing that CSS is altering is `<a class="link4" href="#">Upcoming Events</a>` nothing else because that class isn't applied to anything else (from what you've posted).

However, you can use general targeting based upon the elements....

```
.block_right_380_text_left ul li a {
    /* CSS to alter the links in the include list when inside the div */
}

li ul li a {
    /* CSS to alter the links in the include list when inside a list itself */
}
```

repeat for each CSS definition.

Altering the a.link4 classes CSS isn't going to do anything other than alter that one single link. Which doesn't *appear* to be part of the include itself.

You *could* be more specific with selectors (which is a good thing) if you merely add a class to the `UL` inside the include.

Note that `ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu` has **zero** bearing on *any* HTML you've posted here. That does *not* mean it can't. It may very well be a good selector to alter the included list..... There's just no way to tell based on what you've posted here.

Comment: There's a separate css file (SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css) for the menu system.  It came with an old version of Adobe Dreamweaver.  I tried addition a class to the <UL> of the INCLUDE file, but I got stuck with how to code one CSS entry when I need two different results.

Comment: The general targeting seems to be getting me part way there.  Can you explain this a bit more?  Why have "ul li a" after the class, and then have "li ul li a" separately?  Is there a place I can read up on this?  Thanks.

Comment: It's just the cascading hierarchy of elements.... the links in your include are in this order : `<ul><li><a>`  So, CSS to target that is `ul li a { }` if that first `ul` is inside a div with the class `.block_right_380_text_left` you can target specifically the ul in THAT div via `.block_right_380_text_left ul li a { }`. Then the other list is inside an `<li>` tag, so changing the parent element/class will target the `<ul>` inside that parent `<li>`. Again, it's just CSS selectors.. you can read more here: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/ or a google search will present more.

Comment: Thanks.  This was very helpful and solved my problem.